# d3.js tree structure text links

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am modifying a tree structure from one of the d3 examples with my own data set in a .json file. I have a working copy with my own data. What I want to do now is modify the text so that they link to corresponding urls. There doesn't seem to be much documentation, that I've found, about how to do this.

This is the example tree that I am using: http://bl.ocks.org/1249394

Any suggestions on where to start?

Comment: ancient answer but here's an example with links and images I thought I'd share: http://bl.ocks.org/mhauserr/6025921

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to put the links in the "name" element in the JSON. You then need to create `svg:a` elements instead of `svg:text` elements for the links and `svg:text` elements inside them. E.g. the line

```
nodeEnter.append("svg:text").text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

becomes

```
nodeEnter.append("svg:a").attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.name; })
.append("svg:text").text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

You could of course have seperate JSON elements for link target and text. See [the SVG spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#Links) for more details on linking.

Alternatively, you could use `svg:foreignObject` to embed HTML for the link. See [here](http://ajaxian.com/archives/foreignobject-hey-youve-got-html-in-my-svg) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Dunno, if this still useful, but you can use only 1 your JSON.

Just return d.something_else_than_name and this "something_else_than_name" must be described in your JSON after "name".

So, for e.g.

```
{"name": "stackoverflow", "link": "http://stackoverflow.com"},
```

and after that in your page you just return it, as said before:

```
.attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.link; })
```

Hope this will be helpful for someone.

Comment: Maybe you could have tried to edit the previous answer... Gonna try myself. Thanks anyway.