# How can I add links to dendrogram texts?

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js

I have applied [clustered dendrogram](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7809166) to show an organization's structure. It works well. In addition, I want to add links to the node texts.

I have added "url" keys to the json array for each node

```
{
    "name": "Institutes",
    "children": [
        {   "name": "Social", "url": "http://social.example.com/" }, 
        {   "name": "Health", "url": "http://health.example.com/" },
        {   "name": "Nature", "url": "http://nature.example.com/" },
        {   "name": "Education", "url": "http://social.example.com/" }
    ]
}
```

There are two problems:

- `<a>` tags do not wrap all the `<text>` element.  it is displayed as `<a></a><text></text>`. I want it to be `<a><text></text></a>`.
- How can I read `url` key from json in order to add it as `href` attribute's value (see the line with comment `//???`) ?

---

```
d3.json("org_chart.json", function(error, root) {
        var nodes = cluster.nodes(root),
                links = cluster.links(nodes);
        var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
                .data(links)
                .enter().append("path")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .attr("d", diagonal);

        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
                .data(nodes)
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "node")
                .attr("transform", function(d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
                });

        node.append("circle")
                .attr("r", 5.1);

        node.append("a")
            .attr("href", "#") //???
            .attr("target","_blank");

        node.append("text")
            .attr("dx", function(d) {
                return d.children ? -9 : 8;
            })
            .attr("dy", 3)
            .style("text-anchor", function(d) {
                return d.children ? "end" : "start";
            })
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.name;
            });
    });
```

---

One more thing:

I have tried

```
node.append("a").attr("href", function (d) { return d.url;});
```

and it returns `undefined`. Also I have tried

```
node.append("a").attr("href", "http://example.com");
```

Although it looks like

```
<g class="node" transform="translate(0,428.74692874692875)">
    <circle r="5.1"></circle>
    <a href="http://example.com/" target="_blank">
        <text dx="-9" dy="3" style="text-anchor: end;">
                Education
        </text>
    </a>
</g>
```

it does not open http://example.com when I click on it.

Comment: Regarding links, you can try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10588490/d3-js-tree-structure-text-links and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104681/hyperlinks-in-d3-js-objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're using [`selection.append(name)`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#append) it returns a new selection containing the appended elements, so you can just do another append directly to it, like so:

```
node.append("a").append("text");
```

In order to obtain the `url` property you need to use an accessor function, like so:

```
node.append("a").attr("href", function (d) {
    return d.url;
});
```

**Edit:**

For links you might need to import the xlink namespace in your html file:

```
<html xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
```

And use namespacing:

```
.append("svg:a").attr("xlink:href", urlAccessor)
```

See [relevant answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104681/hyperlinks-in-d3-js-objects).

Comment: `node.append("a").append("text");` is good but the second one is not. I've already tried that `function (d) {return d.url;});` which did not work. returns `undefined`

Comment: @zkanoca You don't have "url" defined on non-leaf elements in your data. You can put a breakpoint or a `console.log(d); return d;` inside of the accessor and check your console.

Comment: It returns `undefined`. and HMTL output is like `<a target="_blank"><text dx="-9" dy="3" style="text-anchor: end;">Education</text></a>`